# .htaccess and mod-rewrite for my wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Any ideas on how to rewrite my admin URLS would greatly be appreciated.

I have created some menus using functions.php and they are working properly but I need a way that I can use on my .htacess to re-write my code.

The original URL is displaying like this:

http://www.website.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=for_buyers

I want it to display like this:

http://www.website.com/wp-admin/menu-sample/submenu-sample/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many pages you have to rewrite the urls for but you could do 301 redirects which be easy for a few pages but a bit dirty.. Since it sounds like you already have the new links set-up

Otherwise you need to look through their php code..

http://www.website.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=for_buyers

Their passing info through the url to direct the user to the correct page.. So they clicked this link, and they set it up so that it goes to page=for_buyers. I would bet this code is in the admin.php, but you would most likely need to edit other php files that get redirected to this admin.php file..

I might be missing your question completely.. Let me know..

RewriteEngine on

redirect 301 /category/product-line/samplepage.htm http://websitename.com/newpage.htm

so the page you are redirecting, just take awaY the domain.com part and start with the slash, then a space, then the full html path of the page you are redirecting to.. start with one and give it a min and see if it works.. then go from there.. the htaccess file should be in your main directory.. wordpress should already have one created and you just add to the end of it..

Good luck -Pat

Comment: I have to re-write 30 link. They are 6 menus and 24 sub menus. I am clueless when it comes to mod-rewrite. the functions were added to my main function.php file.

Comment: if you have the new pages set up with the urls you want its easy, go into your htaccess file through ftp.. updated answer..

Comment: I know how to get to the .htaccess I just don't know how to write the RewriteEngine on wp-admin using my URL: http://www.website.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=for_buyers

Comment: What about trying to change your permalink settings.. in the wordpress dashboard, goto settings, then permalinks, change the option to postname.. click save.. that will rewrite your urls to show page names and not the random php code.. If your using a custom plugin with its own url structure, well then you are prab sol unless you are fluent in reading php..

Comment: Thank you Pat for your comments and help I appreciate it. My Permalinks are set and you are right about PHP and me SOL lol. I have to figure out a way to re-write the rule for each link but I just need to know how for one and the rest comes easy. Cheers! John

Comment: http://www.website.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=for_buyers, that link, the plugin is using the php code to send the user to the page after the ? mark, he is passing info through the url.. unless you can rewrite his code, you aren't changing that.. you can redirect urls, but the url you redirect to has to have a page there.. you cant mask urls with fake urls.. hope that helps.. Download his plugin folder, open it with notepad ++ and just take a look, you might get lucky, php isn't that complicated.. unless he encrypted it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your settings > permalinks and select `Post name`

Thanks.